# jQuery: If Mouse Hovering When Page Loads…

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I'm having a tricky time working through a jQuery issue. The page has a feature image. When the user hovers on the feature image, a transparent overlay with some supporting content fades in, and if they move their mouse outside the feature the supporting bar fades out. So far so good, but…

I'd like to have the transparent overlay fade in, hold a few seconds, then fade out when the page loads (like a sneak peak). Pretty easy, I thought. But, what I didn't consider was that the function also needs to check to see if the mouse is already over the feature area when the page is loaded. If it is, the support bar shouldn't fade out until the user isn't hovering on the feature area (e.g., the initial auto fade out is skipped). So:

- Page loads
- If the mouse isn't over the feature area, show the overlay, wait
  a few secs, fade it out
- If the mouse is over the feature area, show the overlay, don't fade
  out until the user leaves the feature
  area
- After the initial run, anytime the user is over the feature the overlay
  fades in, when they mouseout the
  overlay fades out

I can't seem to figure out a clean way to do this (I'd rather not have to track the mouse coords). Any ideas appreciated :)

Here's the page: http://collective.poccuo.com/

And here's what I have at the moment:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
    $('#content.homepage #support').show().delay(2000).fadeOut(100,function(){
        $('#content.homepage').hover(function(){
            $("#content.homepage #support").delay(500).fadeIn(350);
         },function(){
            $("#content.homepage #support").fadeOut(150);
        });
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should do it like this:

```
   var hideInitially = true; //This var does the magic
   $(window).load(function(){  
        $('#content.homepage').hover(function(){
            $("#content.homepage #support").delay(500).fadeIn(350);
            hideInitially= false; //If there has been a hover, don't hide on load
         },function(){
            $("#content.homepage #support").fadeOut(150);
        });
    $('#content.homepage #support').show();
    setTimeout(function(){ //Same as delay
       if(hideInitially) $('#content.homepage #support').fadeOut(100);  //Only hide if there wasn't a hover      
    }, 2000);
 });
```

What this code does is to prevent initial hiding if there has been a hover.
Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Set a timeout which hides the `div`, but clear the timeout when the user hovers the item, so it won't fade out automatically anymore.

```
var timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
    $("#content.homepage #support").trigger('mouseout')
},4000);

$('#content.homepage #support').show();


        $('#content.homepage').hover(function(){
            window.clearTimeout(timeout);
            $("#content.homepage #support").fadeIn(350);
         },function(){
            $("#content.homepage #support").fadeOut(150);
        });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/4sejb/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `.mouseenter()` doesn't get called if you're already on top of the item. However, `.mousemove()` does. This doesn't let you "detect" them without moving their mouse, but if they haven't moved their mouse, it's probably safe to go ahead and hide the overlay, re-showing it whenever they do move.

If you REALLY want to detect that they start with their mouse on top of your item **without** them moving their mouse, you should be able to grab the cursor position and test it against the screen position of your item.

```
$('#yourdiv').hover(function() {
    // Show the thing
    // This is the "normal" show it scenario
}, function() {
    // Hide the thing
    // We always want to hide it when they leave
}).mousemove(function() {
    // Show the thing; if this is bound and they move on #yourdiv, you want to show it

    // However, this is only meaningful the first time, so stop tracking mousemove
    $(this).unbind('mousemove');
});
```